# Difference between document.write(X) & document.getElementById("").innerHTML = X

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, document.write

New to javascript, apology if this is a dumb question. The two statement in the title seems to be doing the same thing, are there any particular difference that I need to be aware of?

Comment: They do not do the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write` can be used to emit markup during the parsing of the page. It cannot be used for modifying the page after it's parsed. The output of document.write goes straight into the parser as though it had been in the HTML document in the first place

`innerHTML`, which is not a function but rather a property, exists on all DOM element instances, and can be used to set their content, using markup. This, along with the various DOM methods available on instances, is the primary way that dynamic web pages are done.

Answer (score 3):

They do *not* do the same thing.  `document.write` will just append to the page as its loading, wherever in the page the `<script>` tag happens to be.  If you call `document.write` *after* the page is loaded, it will **erase** the entire page before appending.

On the other hand, `document.getElementById("").innerHTML = ''` *replaces* the HTML of a certain element with what you give it (you can also append with `.innerHTML += ''`).

It's *highly* suggested not to use `document.write` in your page.